# Configure proxy settings for symbol server

Tags: visual-studio, proxy

I am working on a .NET 4.5 application and am trying to get the Microsoft symbols. In Options -> Debugging -> Symbols I have a location entry for "http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols" checked. When I start debugging I see a dialog that looks like it is downloading the symbols. However, when I go to my symbols cache folder I see it has created a FailedLoads folder with a bunch of text files in there for all the symbols with contents "PDB Not Found". I am thinking that I need to configure my proxy settings manually. Is there a way I can do that (configure the proxy settings for the symbol server)?